# In Databricks, What could be the difference between writing delta tables in one notebook or more?

Tags: databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta

I'd like to know which one is better for below:

1. Using one notebook:

- Notebook A: Read from Kafka Topic A, writing to Delta B, C after conditional filtering

2. Using multiple notebooks:

- Notebook B: Read from Kafka Topic A, writing to Delta B after conditional filtering
- Notebook C: Read from Kafka Topic A, writing to Delta C after conditional filtering

When I tried in my end, it didn't look so different. Anyone can explain which one is better and what could be best practices when you have many Kafka topics to ingest? Is it better to have one notebook per topic and one notebook per delta table?